# How clone private submodule GitHub for GitLab CI

Tags: git, github, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have follow situation:
I am doing GitLab CI with private submodule from GitHub, and getting next messages in my pipeline:

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such
> device or address fatal: clone of
> 'https://github.com/username/project' into submodule path
> '/my_gitlab_username/my_gitlab_project' failed

> fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': No such
> device or address fatal: clone of
> 'https://github.com/username/project' into submodule path
> '/my_gitlab_username/my_gitlab_project' failed
>
> Failed to clone 'submodule_name' a second time, aborting

**How can I set token or something helpful for cloning GitHub private repo?**

Answer (score 1):

To clone repository, you might need to use token:

git config --global credential.helper store

git clone https://your_username:your_github_token@github.com/username/private-repo.git

Otherwise use curl api calls

Answer (score -1):

Docs taken from [gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/git_submodules.html)

When you use Git submodules, your project should have a file named `.gitmodules`. You might need to modify it to work in a GitLab CI/CD job.

For example, your `.gitmodules` configuration might look like the following if:

Your project is located at `https://gitlab.com/secret-group/my-project`.
Your project depends on `https://gitlab.com/group/project`, which you want to include as a submodule.
You check out your sources with an SSH address like `git@gitlab.com:secret-group/my-project.git`.

```
[submodule "project"]
  path = project
  url = ../../group/project.git
```

When your submodule is on the same GitLab server, you should use relative URLs in your .gitmodules file. Then you can clone with HTTPS in all your CI/CD jobs. You can also use SSH for all your local checkouts.

The above configuration instructs Git to automatically deduce the URL to use when cloning sources. Git uses the same configuration for both HTTPS and SSH. GitLab CI/CD uses HTTPS for cloning your sources, and you can continue to use SSH to clone locally.

For submodules not located on the same GitLab server, use the full URL:

```
[submodule "project-x"]
  path = project-x
  url = https://gitserver.com/group/project-x.git
```